# Zsh, Indirect array variable assignment without using eval

Tags: zsh, variable, array, function

I have a variable `VARNAME` which contains a name of another variable. I'd like to assign to this another variable without using `eval`. How can I do that?

Th reason I don't want to use `eval` is the following. Assume first a function for prepending `foo` variable:

```
% prepend_foo() { foo=("$@" $foo) }
% foo=(1 2)
% print -l $foo
1
2
% prepend_foo x 'a b c' y
% print -l $foo
x
a b c
y
1
2
%
```

Now consider a generalized function for appending to any variable:

```
% prepend() { var=$1; shift; eval "$var=($@ ${(P)var})" }
% foo=(1 2)
% print -l $foo
1
2
% prepend foo x 'a b c' y
% print -l $foo
x
a
b
c
y
1
2
%
```

As you can see, variables with spaces are split into several array items. I couldn't properly combine quote to achieve desired thing.

---

On IRC, someone suggested using `${name::=word}`, but that doesn't work well with arrays:

```
21:23 < someone> > b=(bar baz); a=b; : ${(P)a::=(foo ${(P)a})}; typeset -p b
21:23 < machabot> someone: typeset b='(foo bar baz)'
21:23 < someone> dammit that's a string
```

Answer (score 6):

To prepend elements to an array, you can just do:

```
a[1,0]=(more elements)
```

Or you can do:

```
a=(more elements "$a[@]")
```

Note that doing:

```
a=(more elements $a)
```

would remove the empty elements in `$a`.

Now, to make a function for that, that's what `eval` is for, but you have to get the syntax right:

```
prepend() {
  eval "${1}[1,0]"='("${@[2,-1]}")'
}
```

See how the `("${@[2,-1]}")` is single-quoted so it is passed literally to `eval`.

Or the longer way, but wouldn't work for `prepend var more elements` (when the variable name is `var`):

```
prepend() {
  local var=$1; shift
  eval "$var"='("$@" "${'"$var"'[@]}")'
}
```

The code you want to `eval` evaluate upon `prepend varname ...` is:

```
 varname=("$@" "${varname[@]")
```

You don't want `"$@"` to be expanded before being passed to `eval`. Only `$var` needs to be expanded there.

Note that the `P` variable expansion flag is as dangerous as `eval` when used with unsanitized data.

```
var='x[$(uname>&2)0]'
echo "${(P)var}"
```

Will run that `uname` command.

Answer (score 2):

Your `prepend` function can be written without `eval`, if you loop over the elements to unshift them one at a time.

```
$ prepend () {
then> local i=$#*
then> while [[ $i > 1 ]]; do
then>   typeset -g "${1}[1,0]=$*[$i]"
then>   i=$((i - 1))
then> done
then> }
$ foo=(a 'b c' d)
$ prepend foo m 'n o p' q r
$ print -l $foo
m
n o p
q
r
a
b c
d
$
```

Note that `-g` is needed for typeset to accept setting a non-local array element, but doesn't mean that the array referenced by `$1` can't be local to the calling function. It just means "it's OK to look up the function call stack to find this array".